# How do I add all the items in my list box and show "total" in the same list box

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I am doing a simple Straight-Line depreciation app. My list box shows the Year and Depreciation amount. In the same list box, I want to add a "total" and sum up all the depreciation. I added a picture of how the app should look like. BTW we are required using a FOR loop.

```
private void calcButton_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //Declare Vairables 
    double cost, salvage, depreciation;
    int usefulLife;
    int total = 0; 


    //grab data
    double.TryParse(assetCostTextBox.Text, out cost);
    double.TryParse(salvageValueTextBox.Text, out salvage);
    int.TryParse(usefulLifeNumericUpDown.Text, out usefulLife);

    //Print heading
    string formatCode = "{0,7}{1,20}";
    depreciationScheduleListBox.Items.Add(string.Format(formatCode, 
    "Years:", "Depreciation:"));
    depreciationScheduleListBox.Items.Add("");

    //use for loop to calculate deprecation value of each year
    int iterations = 0;
    for (iterations = 1; iterations <= usefulLife; iterations += 1)
    {
        depreciation = (cost - salvage) * 1/usefulLife;
        depreciationScheduleListBox.Items.Add(string.Format(formatCode, 
         iterations, depreciation.ToString("C2")));


    }
```

[Here is a picture of the app](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rggFB.png)

Comment: SO is not a place to get people to do your homework for you.  You do what you think is required and, if it doesn't work, show us what you did and explain how the result doesn't meet your needs.

Answer (score 0):

How about this ?

```
double total = depreciationScheduleListBox.Items.Cast<string>().Select((string item) => Convert.ToDouble(System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Match(item, "Depreciation: \\$(.+)").Groups[1].Value)).ToArray().Sum();
```

I converted the items of your listBox to IEnumerable.
Then, I got what after `Depreciation: $` which should be the number.
Then, I converted this string output to Double and got at final `double[]` then got its sum